# JSP to direct one jsp page to another using button type

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea

I need to direct one jsp page through button click.I have tried out this scenario using below code I couuld not direct to that page.

```html
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: rajee
  Date: 2/15/15
  Time: 12:20 PM
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
    try{
        String user=request.getParameter("user");
        String pass=request.getParameter("pass");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/surveysample","root","root");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from userdetail where name='"+user+"' and password='"+pass+"'");
        int count=0;
        while(rs.next()){
            count++;
        }
        if(count>0){
            out.println("welcome "+user);
        }
        else{
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
%>
<html>
<script>
</script>
<br>
<head>
    Summary Survey Details
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Recent Survey details</h1>
    <table border="3">
        <thead>survey details</thead>
        <th>Family  name</th>
        <th>First  name</th>
        <th>Middle  name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Birthday</th>
        <th>Income Group</th>
        <th>Complete Address</th>
        <th>Cordinates</th>
        <th>Mobile number</th>
        <th>email address</th>
        <th>Present Internet Provider</th>
        <th>Positive comments with present provider</th>
        <th>Negative remarks with present provider</th>
    </table>
    <a href="CreateSurvey.jsp">Create New Survey</a>
    <form name="SurveyMenu" action="SurveyMenu" method="get">
        <input type="button" value="Create new Survey" name="CreateSurvey" onclick="document.forms[0].action = 'CreateSurvey.jsp'; return true;" />
        &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel" name="Cancel"  />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Can you please explain ahy this is not happened when I click the button create new survey?

this is my code for login part

```html
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: rajee
  Date: 2/15/15
  Time: 12:18 PM
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<script>
    function validate(){
        var username=document.form.user.value;
        var password=document.form.pass.value;
        if(username==""){
            alert("Enter Username!");
            return false;
        }
        if(password==""){
            alert("Enter Password!");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
<form name="form" method="post" action="check.jsp" onsubmit="javascript:return validate();">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="user"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="pass"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><a href="register.jsp">Register Here</a></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Raji, welcome to SO! I wanted to introduce you to my good friend [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: you have to give username, password from another page, can you please show that code?

Comment: I have edited my question and added the requested code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either, change the `onclick` handler code to

```
onclick="javascript:document.forms[0].action = 'CreateSurvey.jsp'; document.forms[0].submit();"
```

Or, change the `<input>` type to `submit` as

```
<input type="submit" value="Create new Survey" name="CreateSurvey"
 onclick="javascript:document.forms[0].action = 'CreateSurvey.jsp'; return true;" />
```